# For Loop in Selenium Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, for-loop, robotframework

I need your expertise to help me implement "for loop" in selenium robot framework. There is a variable which was converted as a set of three values. We need to verify existence of each value from this set with a table row. Can you please advice some solution. I used following for loop:
${list} is a set of following three variable ['1xxx','2xxx','3xxx']

```
    :FOR    ${rows}      IN     ${list}
            ${row}=      Verify Table Row Info      table_xpath     ${rows}
```

I thought the above code will verify one item at a time with table row values, instead it is taking entire set of values to compare with table row values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@{list}` instead of `${list}`:

```
:FOR    ${rows}      IN     @{list}
        ${row}=      Verify Table Row Info      table_xpath     ${rows}
```